# Exporting Entire Registry To Relative Path

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windows-8.1

Using the following code

```
REGEDIT /E C:\output.reg
```

A registry dump file is created in C directory. It overwrites automatically when a file with the same name exists. When I try changing the output directory to relative path like this

```
REGEDIT /E output.reg
```

it wouldn't work.

No file is created but processing takes just as long as usually. Which code can export the whole registry using relative path?

Like requested, the .bat code including debug code:

```
ECHO %CD%
REGEDIT /E output.reg
PAUSE
```

Command line output:

```
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New_folder>ECHO C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New_folder
C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New_folder

C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New_folder>REGEDIT /E output.reg

C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New_folder>PAUSE
Press any key to exit . . .
```

Folder before (and after) .bat file execution:
[image]

Comment: Be more specific about your system details and how you invoked the command please.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza How about you be more specific. The code in your question works fine for both Harry and myself. The problem appears to be with your environment.

Comment: @David Heffernan I added tags about my system above. I create a new .bat file inside a new folder containing the code mentioned and ran it by double-clicking. It processed the request and closed the cmd window but no file showed up in the folder as opposed to absolute path.

Comment: What would also be useful would be your batch script file, including the debugging code you added, the location of that file, i.e. the working directory, and the output of the batch script.

Comment: @David Heffernan I added everything to the top post

Comment: Good work. I can repro. Don't know why, but I at least have a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, it works! You should put quotation marks around it though since it will fail if the folder names have blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the command given in your question is already fine. If you supply a relative path for the output file name then the file will be created relative to the current working directory. This is easily verified from an interactive command prompt.

Whatever is going wrong with your batch script, the problem is not as you have currently surmised. Some of the more obvious explanations include:

1. The working directory is not what you think it is. Verify it by adding debug code to your script to emit the working directory.
2. The file is locked for some reason and so regedit cannot write to the file.
3. You don't have sufficient rights to write to the working directory.

**Update**

Thanks a lot for your question update.  I tried to re-create your scenario (I'm on Windows 7 but I doubt that matters) and indeed I find the same issue as you. The command works fine from an interactive console window, but not when executing in a batch script.

I've no idea why this is, but here a simple enough workaround is to supply a full path:

```
REGEDIT /E %cd%\output.reg
```

Comment: Debug code seems to give me just the directory I'm in. Any specific code you thought of? The file is not locked, it has yet to be created. If the syntax is correct too, there must be something wrong with the command in general or the working directory really is seen differently than expected.